# Comparing signs of Fixnums in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to compare just the signs of two Fixnums. Right now I am using:

```
c = -c if (a >= 0.0 && b < 0.0) || (a < 0.0 && b >= 0.0)
```

I would like something like:

```
c = -c if a.sign != b.sign
```

or perhaps some other way of comparing only the signs.

Comment: If it's important I'd probably just patch it in; AFAIK only BigNum has a `sign` method.

Comment: What is `c`? What are `a`, `b`? And most importantly, **what is your question?**

Comment: @sawa - I am trying to find the shortest, most elegant way to perform a conditional operation (like flipping the sign on a number: `c = -c`) when a (a signed Fixnum) has the opposite sign of b (another signed Fixnum). So if a = -34 and b = 7 then c would = -c.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just multiplication:

```
c = -c if a*b < 0
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice, short solution. I'll benchmark it against the `c = -c if (a<0) != (b<0)` suggestion above.

Comment: I was wondering which one would be faster, though unless you're calling it many (millions) times, it won't matter. The main thing is using whichever one is easier or clearer for you.

Comment: I am using it to switch the amplitude on an audio filter. So, in fact, I _will_ be calling it many millions of times.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `a >= 0` for a similar purpose as "`a.sign`", with `true` for positive (non-negative) and `false` for negative:

```
c = -c if (a>=0) != (b>=0)
```

If you're using it often, and you want a more Ruby-esque feel, it might be worth your while to go with the comment above and patch this in, as something like `Numeric#pos?` maybe.

Comment: Comparing booleans isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. I believe: `c = -c if (a<0) != (b<0)` would work too.

Comment: Yeah, it just depends on which one you want to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This question made me start rooting around in my assembler toolbox, which I haven't had open for years. I think this'll do what you're looking for:

```
c = -c if (a < 0) ^ (b < 0)
```

Here's what it's doing:

```
irb(main):006:0> true ^ true
=> false
irb(main):007:0> true ^ false
=> true
irb(main):008:0> false ^ true
=> true
irb(main):009:0> false ^ false
=> false
```

Depending on your code, an alternate way is to use it could be in a ternary statement:

```
((a < 0) ^ (b < 0)) ? -c : c
```

Here's some benchmark code and results:

```
require 'benchmark'

puts `ruby -v`

N = 10_000_000

A = 1
B = 1
Benchmark.bm(5) do |bench|
  bench.report('^') { N.times { (A < 0) ^ (B < 0) } }
  bench.report('!=') { N.times { (A>=0) != (B>=0) } }
  bench.report('<') { N.times { A*B < 0 } }
end

ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
            user     system      total        real
^       5.740000   0.000000   5.740000 (  5.743873)
!=      4.300000   0.000000   4.300000 (  4.304685)
<       3.310000   0.000000   3.310000 (  3.312378)

ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
            user     system      total        real
^       1.480000   0.000000   1.480000 (  1.484879)
!=      1.400000   0.000000   1.400000 (  1.401381)
<       1.260000   0.000000   1.260000 (  1.256628)
```

That's with 10M loops, which is a heap o' looping. Looks like it's steenslag FTW!

Comment: Wow. That's beautiful! Thank you so much! I don't have enough 'reputation' to even upvote yet. Wow... ruby 2.0 is fast! I don't think there's anything preventing me from using it. Thank you, the Tin Man. 10,000,000 loops is 3:28 seconds of audio. So you see, the loops build up fast!